# How to get the content type of a REST request in a Zend Framework 2 controller?

Tags: http, rest, request, zend-framework2, content-type

The `Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController#requestHasContentType(...)` checks the content using `$request->getHeaders()->get('content-type');`.

Now I'm sending a cURL request like this:

```
# curl -i http://project.dev/seminars/1 -H 'Accept: allication/xml'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 14 Jun 2013 16:06:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze15
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 1108
Content-Type: text/html
```

So, the content type is `text/html`. But the output, I'm getting is `false`:

```
$test = $this->getRequest()->getHeaders()->get('content-type');
var_dump($test);
// output: bool(false)
```

What I'm doing wrongly and how should I do, in order to get the contetn type of the REST request?

---

My bad -- I was expecting the `Accept` value from `$request->getHeaders()->get('content-type')`. Instead of it I should use `$this->getRequest()->getHeaders()->get('Accept')`.

Comment: Are those the headers you get back from the curl request? If so, they're the headers your action sent back in the response, and not the headers you sent in the request (which only contain an Accept header). You should be getting the accept header from the request headers and setting the appropriate content-type for the response headers

Comment: @Crisp Thank you for your comment! Yes, you are right, it's the response meta information.